# Same old story, vertical alignment of minipages

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, minipage

I have very little knowledge about Latex, so even after searching and digging through dozens of pages, I still don't know how to solve my problem.
So I got this document with this:

```
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{minipage}[t]{77mm}
\begin{tabular*}{75mm}{rl}
A: & \begin{minipage}[t]{62mm}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \end{minipage} \\
B: & \begin{minipage}[t]{62mm}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... \end{minipage} \\
C: & \begin{minipage}[t]{62mm}consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor \end{minipage} \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{77mm}
\begin{tabular*}{75mm}{rl}
A: & \begin{minipage}[t]{62mm} sed diam voluptua.\end{minipage} \\
B: & \begin{minipage}[t]{62mm}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \end{minipage} \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\end{footnotesize}
```

The Problem is, that the minipages do not align to top if one of them has more lines than the other. See sample picture:

[image]

How can I make both be on the same line?

Comment: Why don't you use  `tabular*{75mm}{rp{62mm}}` rather than inserting a `minipage[t]{62mm}` in each cell of the second column?

Comment: The minipage makes it easier to change the flow..  like putting a D on top of the right A.. so messy with a nested tabular - not?

Comment: For such things, you can simply use `\stackover{D}{A}` (from `stackengine`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As coded, the `tabular*` environments also have to be top-aligned.  You might, however, consider replacing the `tabular*` with some sort of `enumerate` environment.

Note: `footnotesize` is not an environment, but a declaration.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{minipage}[t]{77mm}
\begin{tabular*}{75mm}[t]{rl}
A: & \begin{minipage}[t]{62mm}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \end{minipage} \\
B: & \begin{minipage}[t]{62mm}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... \end{minipage} \\
C: & \begin{minipage}[t]{62mm}consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor \end{minipage} \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{77mm}
\begin{tabular*}{75mm}[t]{rl}
A: & \begin{minipage}[t]{62mm} sed diam voluptua.\end{minipage} \\
B: & \begin{minipage}[t]{62mm}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \end{minipage} \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here is the simpler enumerate environment version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{minipage}[t]{71mm}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*:,parsep=0pt]
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... 
\item consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor  
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}\hspace{6mm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{71mm}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*:,parsep=0pt]
\item sed diam voluptua.
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I also appreciate the Note. ;) so with it was easier to learn Latex - such a steep learning curve.